# Looking for a specific midi soundfont/patch

Tags: sound, midi

I'm looking for a very specific set of Midi patch/soundfont files. I want to replicate the Microsoft GS Wavetable patches in Guitar Pro (using Timidity on Linux). So far I am pretty satisfied with the eawpats files that I finally found to replace the terrible freepats sound, which do come pretty close but they're not *quite* the same. Call me sadistic for specially seeking out those old sounds but it's what I listened to for years using that software so I guess I'm accustomed to it hah.  But from a technical standpoint it would also help me with adjusting audio levels as most users of Guitar Pro would be using a Windows OS anyway. Thanks for any advice on answering this obscure question.

Example below:

> [Doom PC Original Soundtrack - 2. At Doom's Gate (E1M1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6WZnsx4Z4U&index=2&list=PL1-kyYqMfjO-TmN1NKniGWTluIklSvqhn)

Sigh maybe I should just dual boot Windows for my audio needs but I'm not giving up just yet!

Comment: 1. Use `gm.dls`. 2. Buy a SoundCanvas.

Comment: Amazing, thank you CL. I did not know that gm.dls was where Windows sourced the samples (or that the file existed at all for that matter). That file name helped me located a converted .sf2 file within minutes and I am now happily listening to the same sounds that were present on my windows installs. + 1 to you good sir!

The link I used was the following: 

http://www.ronimusic.com/smp_ios_dls_files.htm . The file name was FreeFont.sf2